# Как мокнуть компонент

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, angular2, typescript

В общем есть компонент на angular4 написал для него тест замокал сервисы, все было норм, теперь добавляю внутри этого компонента вызов другого

```
 <app-user-filter></app-user-filter>
```

получаю ошибку

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
'app-user-filter' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-user-filter' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

    import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {UserComponent} from '../user.component';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';
import {UserService} from '../user.service';
import {MockUserService} from './mockObjects/MockUserService';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {MockActivatedRoute} from './mockObjects/MockActivatedRoute';
import set = Reflect.set;

describe('UserComponent', () => {
    let component: UserComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [UserComponent],
            imports: [
                NgxPaginationModule
            ]
        }).overrideComponent(UserComponent, {
            set: {
                providers: [
                    {provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService},
                    {provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: MockActivatedRoute}
                ]
            }
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: очевидно нужно добавить модуль :)

Comment: @Grundy так это же компонент, самописный, а не модуль, просто один input вынесенный в отдельный компонент

Comment: может как то в declarations  добавить и  потом overrideComponent, пробую так но всеравно рендерить пытается

Comment: ну ты хотя б код тест и подготовки покажи

Comment: @Grundy добавил код, но думаю вряд ли поможет, это стандартный тест

Comment: Собственно, достаточно добавить нужный компонент в секцию declarations для тестового модуля

Comment: пробовал он пытается отрисовать этот компонент

Comment: отрисовать где? :-) в тесте?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63440/discussion-between-grundy-and-serge-esmanovich).

Comment: Мокнуть = сымитировать для тестов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать пустой компонент прямо в тесте:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-user-filter",
    template: ""
})
class FilterStubComponent{}
<...>
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    UserComponent
    FilterStubComponent
  ]
<...>
```

Альтернативный вариант - просто игнорировать такие ошибки ([подробнее](https://angular.io/guide/testing#shallow-component-tests-with-no_errors_schema)):

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA }          from '@angular/core';
...

beforeEach( async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ UserComponent ],
    schemas:      [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
  })
<...>
```

Comment: спасибо помогло